# What is the WinApi call to unmount a registry hive?

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

A tool is mounting a hive at the root of the Registry with a GUID as the name.  Normally after the tool is done running, it unmounts the hive.  However, in some circumstances, the tool gets killed before it can unmount the hive.

I would like to write a program to detect these extraneous GUID hives and unmount them.  Only thing is, I'm not sure:

- what the Win32 API call is to enumerate hives at the root of the Registry (normally enumeration requires a root key)
- if the call to unmount a hive is different than that of deleting a key.

The C# API only appears to support deleting sub keys, does the Win32 API support more?

Comment: you need [`RegUnLoadKeyW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regunloadkeyw)

Comment: What do I pass for hkey then, given that the hive appears to be mounted at the root of the registry, so there is no subkey involved here.  Or does it just appear to be mounted there and is actually mounted somewhere else?

Comment: `RegUnloadKey` unloads a *subkey* that was loaded with `RegLoadKey`, which does not load *root hives*. Unless you are thinking of a hive that is loaded under `HKEY_USERS`.

Comment: @user2460953 can you show a screenshot of the GUID hives you are seeing?

Comment: ok, really need use [`ZwUnloadKey`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntzwapi.h#L4250) and [`ZwLoadKey`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntzwapi.h#L1930) if you want load/unload **root** hive. but *regedit* not view such key/hive. only special tools can show it - https://i.imgur.com/pGez6uI.png

Comment: Hmm, I was seeing it in regedit, I'll see if I can get a screenshot

Comment: @user2460953 Mounting is a process makes data on a storage device available for users to access via the computer's file system. Unmounting cuts off all user access to the data. [From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing))].  What's your use case here? Do you want to remove user access or delete?

Comment: @user2460953, if you saw it in regedit, then I don't think it was mounted in the "\REGISTRY" Key. AFAIK, regedit only enumerates the predefined pseudo-handles such as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, which the Windows API maps to a real Key handle when accessed (e.g. a handle for "\REGISTRY\MACHINE"). The NT registry API can use fully-qualified paths starting in NT's "\" root object directory, but the Windows registry API only exposes the ability to open a Key relative to a [`RootDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntdef/ns-ntdef-_object_attributes) Key handle.